# Can OpenVPN Access Server upgrade the underlying OpenVPN version?

Tags: amazon-web-services, openvpn, amazon-ami

I'm currently running OpenVPN Access Server 2.1.0, using an AWS AMI. Looking at the upgrades available for Access Server, the latest is 2.1.4. Does this use OpenVPN version 2.1 under the hood, or a later version? If it's using 2.1, is there a way to use OpenVPN 2.4.3 with Access Server 2.1?

Comment: I see no indication that these are bundled packages. Although the technology is the same, they are different servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked OpenVPN support about this. Their response:

> What you refer to as version 2.4 is not the OpenVPN Access Server. That must be the open source OpenVPN program you are referring to. Since these are 2 different programs, the version numbers don't in any way correspond. So upgrade from Access Server to the open source OpenVPN program is simply not possible; they are different programs. The latest version of OpenVPN Access Server is version 2.1.6, and that version does take care of a number of security issues that were discovered a few weeks ago. But the security issues that were discovered a few days ago, are not yet fully addressed in Access Server 2.1.6.

So as Jacob Evans commented, these are different pieces of software, and it's not possible to have Access Server use a more recent version of the open source OpenVPN.